# Client Credentials flow in Azure supported?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

Title says it all. We want to use the OAuth2 CC flow for authenticating native clients without any user interaction at all.

Is this flow supported by Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

And it's supported in ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016).

Comment: Nice to hear, do you have a src for that information?

Comment: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/looking-at-the-different-oauth2-flows-supported-in-azuread-for-office-365-apis